# "Living in the South" or "Living in the south"?

Tags: capitalization

The sentence I'm wondering about:

> Living in the [S/s]outh during the early 1900’s, the most decisive
>   factor of a man’s life was determined at birth: the color of his skin.

Should South be capitalized because it's a noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"South" here is a proper noun, so it needs to be capitalized.  Yes, everytime "south" is being used to indicate a place, it needs to be capitalized.

When I say "indicate", I mean used in their name, i.e. South Pole, or The South Country, or South Australia, or just "The South"

Comment: *In Italy, those who live in the south are often looked down on by those in the north*. I don't think that *requires* capitalisation. But certainly OP's example does - as you say, because it's a proper noun. In my example it's part of a 'locatory adjectival phrase', to coin a phrase. Different enough to me that I wouldn't capitalise it.

Comment: Most information, first reply. And that's a good point @FumbleFingers, thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

South here is referring to the Southern United States, not merely the cardinal direction, so it should be capitalized.

Comment: It's a bit parochial to assume Southern US - it could have been Southern UK! I'd like to hope colour prejudice was less here 100 years ago than in the US, but that's probably just wishful (read, parochial) thinking! :)

Comment: Ah, true enough, I just assumed.

Comment: ...having said that, +1 for making the point (or at least, implying) that 'south' is only capitalised if it refers to a specific area known by that name, not if it's just a general direction indicator.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers have indicated, it should be *the South*. However, I think it needs to be made clear that the reason is that "the South" is a *proper noun* referring to the southern part of the United States. Most of the time, *south* is used as a common noun and does not need to be capitalized:

> I live to **the south**.
>
> The wind blew in from **the south**.
>
> Keep going towards **the south** until you see the big tree.

The word *south* only needs to be capitalized when it's part of a proper name, either the official name of a territory such as *South Dakota* or *New South Wales*, or the name of the region of the US known as *the South*.

*The West* is also frequently used as a proper noun to refer to the western region of the United States. Somewhat less frequently you may also see *the North* or *the East* used as proper nouns.