# Should "global south" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, geography

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North%E2%80%93South_divide

In a context such as,

> The harsh realities as the result of the socioeconomic conditions plaguing the global south

Should it be "Global South"

or "global south"?

Comment: Similar: [East Coast, East coast, or east coast?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242399), [“The Midwest of the U.S.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1937), [“Living in the South” or “Living in the south”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33767)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a bit of variance among style guides, but **The Chicago Manual of Style** would capialize "Global South" as like Deep South. Unless, the intention of the writer is "to the south of."

Comment: Interesting, I suppose it makes sense since "global south" is two words with otherwise clear meanings, and them being next to each other does not necessarily symbolize a special term.

Comment: However, if by "south" the writer means the entire Southern Hemisphere, and by "global" the writer is providing nothing more than clarification, I think you can make an argument for __global South__, but that's a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Jaico: Global South is well enough established in specific academic disciplines to be considered as a 'special term'. It references specific theoretical arguments and lines of thought in published academic literature.